# SSRS New Dataset - Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, reporting-services

Hopefully someone can help with this before I rip all my hair out :)

I've created a new data source, ODBC to a postgreSQL DB.  Connection sets up fine and test connection is successful.

launch report builder to create a new dataset, select my new data source.

popup asks for Data Source Credentials,  I enter the creds and then I get the following error:

> Unable to connect to data source 'DSNAME'
>
> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

sql 2012, report builder 3, 64bit PostgreSQL Unicode driver

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Based on some light research, you may have to set a 32 bit ODBC datasource. It's not exactly the same but I found the information here (https://www.xtivia.com/data-source-name-not-found-no-default-driver-specified-system-data-odbc-odbcconnection-handleerror/) .

Comment: just tried that.  test connection fails:  
ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Comment: i created a 64 and 32 bit DSN,  cant connect to the 32 but 64 creates the data source, same error when creating a dataset though

Comment: Do you have access to the ODBC configuration _on the server itself_? It could be the problem based in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137618/why-error-odbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-works-fine-on)

Comment: Yes,  thats where I created the System DSNs and have verified the names match