# Python SQL Alchemy: Writing Python Dataframe to MSSQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to write my python dataframe to a MSSQL server.  The table design has already been created in the server.

Below is the code I am attempting to use.  But I get an error.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pyodbc

engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://username:password@server/database', echo = True)

# engine
df_EVENT5_14.to_sql("MODREPORT", engine)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Duplicate one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137618/why-error-odbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-works-fine-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use correct connection string as below

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+user+':'+password+'@'+host+':'+port+'/'+database+'?'\
      +'driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
```

Please make sure that, put correct details into variables that used in connection string. You may use different driver as well according to your please change the driver, in my case I put SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0.